# I can't get the linkedin access token with axios, keep getting status 400

Tags: node.js, axios, linkedin-api

The API says that status code 400 is probably syntax error, but I wasn't able to find it. I already have the authentication code and app credentials, and the url is registered.

I've tried with and without qs.

```
exports.getAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
    let payload = req.body;
    let request_body = qs.stringify({
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": payload.code,
        "redirect_uri": linkedin.redirect_uri,
        "client_id": linkedin.clientId,
        "client_secret": linkedin.clientSecret
    });
    let config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    };
    axios.post("https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", request_body, config).then(
        response => {
            res.json(response.data);
        },
        error => {
            res.json(error);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62933774/unable-to-get-access-token-for-linkedin-using-axios/65718969#65718969

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong url to get accesstoken.

- Step 1

First you need to use following url

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=https://getpostman.com/oauth2/callback&state=CA&scope=r_emailaddress%20r_ads%20w_organization_social%20rw_ads%20r_basicprofile%20r_liteprofile%20r_ads_reporting%20r_organization_social%20rw_organization_admin%20w_member_social' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 1c7d6199-f41b-43bc-b9ae-10d4bde0d968' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

Response contains code which needs to used in Step 2

- Step 2

use CODE received from Step 1

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=[CODE]&redirect_uri=https://getpostman.com/oauth2/callback&client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&client_secret=[CLIENT_SECRET]' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: f9542a93-fc9d-4cc4-aa38-a10f6cf2eb6f' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

This will give you the access Token

Comment: It looks like in the original question, they have already done step 1. The issue they are having is with step 2 and getting it to work programatically with axios.