# Unable to get access token for linkedin using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios, linkedin-api

I am trying to get access token following the steps described in [Linkedin Oauth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/marketing/context). I am trying to perform step 2 in the process to get an access token. I am using Axios for the POST request. Here is the code I am using (The client secret and id is not real for security reasons):

```
    const axios = require('axios');
    const qs = require('qs');
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken',   
        data: qs.stringify({
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            code: 'AQSow7V6s2F2koWzIsnVKcQGt_cHtsM1F3FHZOrEV0UY1KIFkWiFJpi8dt1NtjuZMOO6-NStoCjTf58awk6GBcH2XQRctt7IBtel4Oeop5yVIBqiedk8qxlIlbkMxlfGg1gCVoupXL6xUc3-jegKYDPSe0rl4mygdpIzGdej2_hhJ827vJcojtvaMXCCGw',
            redirect_uri: 'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fcompany%2Ftttrrr878',
            client_id: '99blt2z20qlm3d',
            client_secret: 'fGGgdqqcx5t3cRfw'       
        }),
        headers: {
            content-type: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
        }
        }).then(result => { 
            console.log(result.data);
        }).catch(error => { 
            console.log(error);
        });
```

I get the following error when I run the code even after making sure that the `code` is not expired (before the 30 min expiration time):

```
data: {
      error: 'invalid_redirect_uri',
      error_description: 'Unable to retrieve access token: appid/redirect uri/code verifier does not match authorization code. Or authorization code expired. Or external member binding exists'
    }
```

However when I do the same thing using curl in the command line as follows, I am able to get the access code:

```
curl -ik -X POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken \
-d grant_type=authorization_code \
-d code=AQSow7V6s2F2koWzIsnVKcQGt_cHtsM1F3FHZOrEV0UY1KIFkWiFJpi8dt1NtjuZMOO6-NStoCjTf58awk6GBcH2XQRctt7IBtel4Oeop5yVIBqiedk8qxlIlbkMxlfGg1gCVoupXL6xUc3-jegKYDPSe0rl4mygdpIzGdej2_hhJ827vJcojtvaMXCCGw \
-d redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fcompany%2Ftttrrr878 \
-d client_id=99blt2z20qlm3d \
-d client_secret=fGGgdqqcx5t3cRfw
```

Any idea why this is happening? Is it somehow related to this
[issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/362) ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. The issue is because you are url encoding the `redirect_uri` parameter, remove that and it should work.

You only need to url encode the redirect_uri parameter when doing the initial request for the access code from the browser.